# How to get specific fields from an api fetch using redux saga

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I in a redux-saga app I made api request and I have loong response.

My saga looks like this:

```
export function* fetchWeatherByCityNameSaga(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(api.getWeatherByCityName, action.payload.city);
    yield put({ type: FETCH_WEATHER_SUCCESS, payload: response });
  } catch (err) {
    yield put({ type: FETCH_WEATHER_START, payload: err });
  }
}

export function* watcherSagas() {
  yield all([
    yield takeLatest(FETCH_WEATHER_START, fetchWeatherByCityNameSaga),
  ]);
}
```

In payload I have something like this:

```
{…}
    city: Object { id: 745042, name: "Istanbul", country: "TR", … }
    cnt: 40
    cod: "200"​
    list: Array(40) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
    message: 0
```

Now what I want to do is creating a new object based on this response object and put that new object to the store. I dont want to have useless data in store. Where should I do it ? In fetchWeatherByCityNameSaga() or in actionCreators or in Component itself?

Comment: what do you mean by `I dont want to useless data in store.`?

Comment: For example list is 40 items array. I only need first of them.From response I only need `city.country` and `list[0].weather.main`

Comment: should be done in action. `fetchWeatherByCityNameSaga`

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new function that takes the response as an argument and returns a new object with only the data you need.

Assuming you are getting an object as a response

For example

```
 function transformWeatherData(response) {
   // make an object with only the data you need
   const data = {
     cityName: response.city.name,
     countryName: response.city.country,
     weatherData: response.list[0].weather.main
   }

   return data;
 }
```

And in the fetchWeatherByCityNameSaga call the function

```
 export function* fetchWeatherByCityNameSaga(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(api.getWeatherByCityName, action.payload.city);

    // call the transform function here
    const result = yield call(transformWeatherData, response);

    // send the result as payload
    yield put({ type: FETCH_WEATHER_SUCCESS, payload: result });

  } catch (err) {
    yield put({ type: FETCH_WEATHER_START, payload: err });
  }
}
```

I would only recommend this way of transforming the data if you already know which fields from the response you need ahead of time. If you do not know that keep the whole response in the store.